# Opening port in pc's firewall and not on network

Tags: networking, lan

If i understand this correctly, when you open a port on a pc's firewall your port will be open to Lan(computers on the same network) this sould not give risks unless your lan network is not safe?

This opened port is open to lan until the port is also forwarded on the router. When thats done there is risks

Right?

Comment: If you do have someone on your LAN that is not trustworthy you're exposed to pretty much the same risks.

Comment: Other then that its safe?

Comment: That's heavily depended on other circumstances some of which are probably outside of your scope. For example if your PC is compromised by other means opening a port isn't going to do much. In addition mechanisms like UPNP might work their magic and setup a port forward without you noticing.

Comment: So i localy want to host a vue web page it gathers information about a machine perfirmance in our factory. Ofcourse we dont want this information accessible for everyone. I figured if i host it localy i can put it on some monitor in the hall and others can log into the protal if need be. For hosting this on LAN i had to open 1port where im hosting on. Is this still safe?

Comment: There is no definitive answer for this. Corporate networks can be quite complex. You might want to talk to your IT. The risk assessment is something you have to do. Ask yourself how probable it is that the service can be exploited in some major way. Talk to your network team to figure out what paths allow access to that server. They might even be able to isolate it. Not being able to reach a server from the internet and being "safe" can be quite different depending on evironment.